# How can I copy a file between server using bsdtar?

Tags: pipe, tar

I'm looking for the fastest way of copying a file between 2 linux servers using bsdtar.

With normal tar, I would do something like:

```
ssh root@remote 'tar -cz -C /my/path/ big_file.txt' | tar -zxv
```

However, just replacing "tar" with "bsdtar" does not seem to work.

So, my questions are:

1. How would I do this with bsdtar?
2. Instead of using gzip, I would like to use something that can use multiple cores for the compress/uncompress, like pbzip2. How would I pipe this in?
3. I want the file "big_file.txt" to be called "hello_world.txt" on the destination server without using a temp-file with renaming. How?

UPDATE 1:

I solved number 1 myself:

```
ssh root@localhost 'bsdtar -cz -f - -C /my/path/ big_file.txt' | tar -zxv
```

UPDATE 2:

I solved number 3 myself:

```
ssh root@localhost 'bsdtar -cz -f - -C /my/path/ big_file.txt' | tar -zxv -O > test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many variations in the syntax of the `tar` command. GNU tar defaults to reading the archive on stdandard input and to writing the archive to standard output, but many other versions default to a tape device. Pass the `f` flag (with or without a dash — I think BSD versions support either) with the argument `-` to indicate stdin or stdout.

If you want to use a different (de)compression program, don't tell `tar` to compress, and pipe into the (de)compression program explicitly.

To rename the file, use the `-s` option, if your version of `tar` supports it (it is similar to the `-s` option of `pax` and to the `--transform` option of GNU tar).

```
ssh root@remote 'cd /my/path && bsdtar cf - -s '/big_file\.txt$/hello.txt/' big_file.txt | pbzip2' | pbzip2 -d | tar xf -
```

If you're only copying a single file, there's no point in using tar unless you both want to preserve metadata and want to use a custom compression program.

```
scp -C -p root@remote:/my/path/hello.txt big_file.txt
```